# How to assign multiple textfield into one variable in xcode 8 ? (Swift 3)

Tags: swift3, xcode8

How do i assign multiple textfield input value into single variable?

I have these two (2) textfield **realname** and **email**

```
    let rn = realname.text
    let em = email.text

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let session   = URLSession.shared

    let request   = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let paramString  = "realname=\(rn)"
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

But the problem is i can only assign it for one input like above

When I try to add like this

```
let paramString  = "real_name=\(rn)&email=\(em)"
```

Apps cannot run/display output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying to append by

```
var paramString = "real_name=\(rn)"
paramString.append("&email=\(em)")
```